# How can I Account the numbers that are between 20 by jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I Account the numbers that are between <=20
I want to be the result: 3

td // 3

I mean
How can I find out how many (td) 
Which is inside the numbers between 20

But how

**I tried this**

```
var h =(this).length;
```

But the wrong result

**jquery**

```
 <script>
$(function(){
  $("#a tr").each(function(){
       var b = $(this).text();
       if(b <= 20){
         $(this).css("color","red");

         var h =(this).length; // How many numbers between b <= 20

         $("#c").text(h);

       }
  });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

**body**

```
<body>
<span>How many numbers <= 20 :</span><span id='c'></span>
<table id='a' border='2'>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>31</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$(function() {
    var res = 0;
    $('#a td').each(function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).text()) <= 20) {
            res++;
            $(this).css("color","red");
        }
    });

    $("#c").text(res);
});
```